# Windows 10 - WMIC/WMI Remote Access denied with local administrator

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, remote-access, wmic

First my **workingsetup:**

**DesktopPC:** Windows 10 Pro, Version: 10.0.10586 Build: 10586, 64-Bit
**Laptop:** Windows 10 Pro, Version: 10.0.10586 Build: 10586, 64-Bit 
**User:** Both computers have the **same** username *{zuka}* & password *{blah}*.

I tried to connect remotely, with WMIC to my DesktopPC, with my Laptop and to execute a query.
I typed these following shell commands into Powershell:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> wmic
    wmic:root\cli> /user: zuka
    Please enter the password:blah
    wmic:root\cli> /node: {IP-Address of my DesktopPC}
    wmic:root\cli> csproduct get /value
    Node - {IP-Address of my DesktopPC}
    Error:
    Description = Access is denied.
```

Or with:

```
    get-wmiobject CIM_Memory -computername desktopPC { or IP } -credential zuka
```

I get a errormessage like:

```
    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I tried to resolve the problem with these following steps:
( But none of them worked :[ )

- Went into secpol.msc & changed *Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts* to **Classic - local users authenticate as themselfes**.
- I also changed in secpol.msc *Network security LAN Manager authentication level* to **Send LM & NTLM responses, use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated**.
- In compmgmt.msc > Service & application > WMI-control > register "security" > expand root & selected **CIMV2** saw that local administrators have fully access to this namespace. Zuka is in a membership of the local administrator group.

Is there a specific issue with Windows 10 or did I miss a certain configuration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To enable remote access for other PC's on WMI, it is needed to add the hosts into the trustedhost-list in winrm, if the computers aren't in the same or any domain.

1. Enable **winrm**. On the computer, you want to access.
   Check if winrm is running or stopped:

   ```
   get-service winrm
   ```

   If it is stopped, type:

   ```
   enable-PSRemoting -force
   ```

   Add access permission to the remote host.

   ```
   winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="REMOTECOMPUTERNAME/IP"}'
   ```

   So in my case:

   ```
   winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="laptopPC"}'
   ```

   To verify the winrm service, you can type:

   ```
   winrm quickconfig
   ```

   It will give the current status of the service and if needed, it will configure the WinRM service.
2. Unfortunately the windows firewall is blocking the remote access.

   1. Go into Windows Firewall with Advanced security > inbound rules mode
   2. Right-click in the working area & choose New Rule...
   3. Choose the predefined option and select Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) from the drop-down list and click next.
   4. Now select the option: (WMI-In) rule with the local profile value.
   5. Allow the connection > Finish.

Now I can acces the WMI from my laptopPC to my desktopPC with this following commandline:

```
 get-wmiobject CIM_Memory -computername desktopPC { or IP } -credential zuka
```

And then it asks for the password. And voilà! I got the information of the memory, trought remote access. =)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a domain set up at home it looks like your passing an incorrect credential.  the user should have a machine qualifier in front of it.  so "/user: desktopPC\zuka"

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it didn't work. :( I still get  Acces denied. Is there a way to test the environment ?

Comment: Easiest way would probably be to try using get-wmiobject, if nothing else it may give you a more detailed error.   in order for that to work you'll need to first create a credential object with get-credential, providing the (qualified) username and password, then using the -credential switch and passing the credential object as the argument.  Alternatively you could try mounting a drive just to make sure that the credentials you are using are working correctly.  

Also check my answer again, I made a typo(now corrected), should be desktopPC\zuka rather than desktopPC/zuka

Comment: Thank, I've got now more information about my issue. I tried your suggestion: `$cred = get-credentional desktopPC\zuka` [ it asked for password ] then I typed `enter-PSSession -computername desktopPC -creditional $red` . Now I got an errormessage that I should put my Laptop to the trustedhost-list. because both computers arent in an domain. I will try to config my laptop into the trustedhost-list.